# Compilando Java por linea de comando

Tags: java, cmd, compilar

Estimados tengo estas instrucciones para compilar un archivo java a traves de cmd

[EDIT]

```
@echo off

rem !!!!!!! Change paths in this section !!!!!!! 
set BASEDIR= D:\Desarrollo\Sonda.NET_v7.0.2231\SondaNetFirmaDigital\java

set SOURCEDIR=%BASEDIR%\Sources\Java
set OUTDIR=%BASEDIR%\Compiled
rem set java_path=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_02\bin
REM set java_path=C:\Java\JDK_1.6\jdk\bin
set java_path=C:\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
set javac=%java_path%\javac.exe

rem !!!!!!!


md %SOURCEDIR%
md Classes

rem copy Classes source files
echo copy Classes source files

set CLASSES_OPTIONS=-d Classes -classpath Classes -sourcepath %SOURCEDIR%

rem Compile Classes
echo Compile Classes

%javac% %CLASSES_OPTIONS% @%SOURCEDIR%\classes.txt

echo perro
if errorlevel 1 goto error_exit
```

y el error que me da es:

```
javac: invalid flag: @
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

No soy experto en java, de hecho es para un trabajo puntual.

Gracias

Comment: Creo que tienes mal el classpath. Si no me equivoco debe ser algo así: `-classpath=%SOURCEDIR%`

Comment: java.exe se usa para ejecutar Java, para compilar se usa javac.exe, luego la variable javac no apunta al ejecutable adecuado

Comment: Dónde define ElDCServerApplet?  Es una carpeta que contiene archivos de typo .class?

Comment: Exacto, me equivoque era javac @PabloLozano pero ahora me da otro error, editare la pregunta gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué pones `@%SOURCEDIR%` en la línea del `javac`? El error indica que la `@` sobra. Prueba a eliminarlo a ver.

Comment: El error era que en la declaracion de variables costante habia espacio D: por si alguien le da ese error, revise eso en primer lugar